# How to conditionally remove the first two characters from a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hive

I have the below data of some phone records, and I want to remove the first two values from each record as they are a country code. What is the way by which I can do this using Scala, [Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark), or [Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hive)?

```
phone
|917799423934|
|019331224595|
|  8981251522|
|917271767899|
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
phone
|7799423934|
|9331224595|
|8981251522|
|7271767899|
```

How can we remove the prefix 91,01 from each record or each row of this column?

Comment: the <space> for / before the 898 entry, is that intentional?

Comment: no not intentional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An improvement I believe, would prefer a list with contains or the equivalent of, but here goes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Tel(telnum: String)
val ds = Seq(
     Tel("917799423934"),
     Tel("019331224595"),
     Tel("8981251522"),
     Tel("+4553")).toDS()

val ds2 = ds.withColumn("new_telnum", when(expr("substring(telnum,1,2)") === "91" || expr("substring(telnum,1,2)") === "01", expr("substring(telnum,3,length(telnum)-2)")).otherwise(col("telnum"))) 

ds2.show
```

returns:

```
+------------+----------+
|      telnum|new_telnum|
+------------+----------+
|917799423934|7799423934|
|019331224595|9331224595|
|  8981251522|8981251522|
|       +4553|     +4553|
+------------+----------+
```

We may need to think of the +, but nothing was stated.

Comment: Can use .isin to compare the 91 and 01 in a simpler fashion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6933993/thebluephantom thanks for the help, it worked.

Comment: can you please explain me substring(telnum,3,length(telnum)-2 what is 3 here @thebluephantom

Comment: starting from 3rd position to bypass in the string 01 & 91

Answer (score 5):

Phone size can be different, such construction can be used (Scala):

```
df.withColumn("phone", expr("substring(phone,3,length(phone)-2)"))
```

Comment: Since the length parameter is optional, `expr("substring(phone,3)")` should be more efficient.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#substring

Answer (score 3):

**Using regular expressions**

Use `regexp_replace` (add more extension codes if necessary):

```
select regexp_replace(trim(phone),'^(91|01)','') as phone --removes leading 91, 01 and all leading and trailing spaces
from table;
```

The same using `regexp_extract`:

```
select regexp_extract(trim(phone),'^(91|01)?(\\d+)',2) as phone --removes leading and trailing spaces, extract numbers except first (91 or 01) 
from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are strings then for a Hive query:

```
sql("select substring(phone,3) from table").show
```