# Using groupby and withcolumn Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i am trying to run the following code and the compilator is currently stuck... I suspect it has something to do with the blocks mention in the title because when i comment one it works normally but without the intended result

```
 def convertSize(size: String): Double = {
    if (size.contains('M')) {
      size.dropRight(1).toDouble
    }
    else {
      size.toDouble / 1000000
    }
  }

  val sizeUDF = udf(convertSize _);

  spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
    //.schema(Gps.schema)
    .csv(Gps.path)
    .groupBy(col("App"),
      col("Rating"),
      col("Reviews"),
      col("Size")
      col("Installs"),
      col("Type"),
      col("Price"), //todo convert
      col("Content Rating"),
      col("Genres"), //todo split
      col("Last Updated"), //todo convert
      col("Current Ver").alias("Current_Version"),
      col("Android Ver").alias("Minimum_Android_Version") 
    )
    .agg(collect_set("Category").alias("Categories"))
    .withColumn("Size", sizeUDF($"Size"))


    .show()
```

Comment: Where you are getting exception, you can use withColumn. And here no need of UDF, you can achieve with by using `case when` condition.

Comment: Im not getting an exception, just stuck in compiler, maybe UDF is too heavy? How should I use ```case when```? Im new to scala and spark...

Comment: `withColumn("Size", when(col("size").contains("M"), col("size").substring(0).cast(DoubleType)).otherwise((col("size")/lit(100000)).cast(DoubleType)))` I haven't tested. just for an idea purpose

Comment: please check  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173674/how-to-conditionally-remove-the-first-two-characters-from-a-column)